# Questions about the requirements to work as contractor in given specialty and/or country on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-topic

Are the questions about the technical and non-technical requirements to work as contractor in given specialty and/or country on topic on that site?

For example, I've asked the following question: [Language requirements for IT-contractor working in Denmark?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/94/language-requirements-for-it-contractor-working-in-denmark) So it's about the language requirements (Danish or only English) to work as contractor in IT specialty in Denmark.

The question is important for contractors planning to look for contract in given country, since the language may be the factor that may make that impossible - for example, in Germany you are expected to know German, the qualification talks are in German too.

Answer (score 5):

I think we have to be careful how granular we get, but it seems to me like such questions generally have a fairly broad audience and are definitively answerable, so they should be on topic.